# Resize JPanel After Process

Tags: java, swing, tabs, resize, panel

I have a problem with my project. I'm making a tool for numerical methods (a lesson in college). I have done nearly all of the project but I have a problem with my design.
When I resize it before making anything it resizes well but, if I set the size of the matrix after the matrice processes the panel isn't resizing.
The code works well if the rank is <=5, but the bigger matrices cause that problem.
I'm using window builder and the code is messy but I'll be glad if you try to help me.

Thanks for your helps!

Comment: Don't expect someone to execute your jar - paste relevant info in the question.

Comment: I tried to add pictures about my problem to my question but the restrictions of the site didn't let me. It works fine with rank<=5 [link](http://imgur.com/yCBhkA6) but if rank>5 the problem occurs [link](http://imgur.com/aFKg7eX) . I can handle it with starting with bigger screen but i want to learn how to fix it. [link](http://i.imgur.com/THbjAUE.jpg) @Java42

Answer (score 2):

Some of things that I noticed in your code.

- Don't use `null` layout at all and avoid `setBounds()` method
- Always hand over it to Layout manager to set the position and size the components.
- Use `ActionListener` for `JButton` instead of `MouseListener` if you want to capture click event only.

**Note:** I can't run your code on my system due to character encoding issue. You have used some character other than English in your code.

Comment: Thanks for tips :) Yes it contains some mathematical symbols like Ɛ (epsilon) and ∆ (delta). These pictures can help me to explain myself. [if the rank is <=5 it works fine](http://imgur.com/yCBhkA6). [But if rank>5 the error occurs](http://imgur.com/aFKg7eX). [I can handle the error with using bigger screen but i want to learn how to fix this](http://i.imgur.com/THbjAUE.jpg) @Braj